# Can steam from my rice cooker's steam vent sanitize sponges?

Tags: cleaning

My rice cooker will vent steam at the red arrow, when the rice is almost cooked. I've been holding my sponges and toothbrush heads over, but not blocking, the steam exhaust to try to sanitize them. Does this work?

I thought about microwaving my sponges, but ["Stop Microwaving Your Sponges, Immediately"](https://www.apartmenttherapy.com/stop-microwaving-your-sponges-immediately-248830)!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If boiling, microwaving or washing sponges in the dishwasher or cloth washer does not disinfect them, steaming them will not, especially in a rice cooker vent where the steam quickly loses temperature.

Throw them away and replace them regularly or, if feeling ecologically conscious, don't use sponges.

Comment: There are biodegradable, compostable sponges (you can even grow them yourself!) for people who are concerned about the environmental aspect of throwing them out regularly.

Answer (score 4):

Steam from rice cookers also carries a certain amount of rice starch which would get deposited on the sponges in the situation you describe.

Rice starch will provide an additional food source for bacteria, likely encouraging their growth.